# CouchDb is not updated when invoke query is executed on fabcar example

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Invoke to fabcar is succesful :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNjTl.png)

However queryAllCars returns empty results
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsRtZ.png)

Docker logs on chaincode container shows the same:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJFem.png)

Hyperledger Fabric Version:1.0.5

**ANSWER:** I have used "AND" in the endorsement policy. I have come across an explanation that "AND" is not supported in peer CLI.This may be the reason why couch db is not updated. stackoverflow.com/a/46052567

Comment: while invoke of fabcar is successful, have you also submitted invoke results to the ordering service so transaction will get ordered and  eventually committed?

Comment: From the screenshots, I think CLI is used to send out the transaction. So @ArtemBarger, is it really needed?

Comment: Yes you right I have missed that.

Comment: I have used "AND" in the endorsement policy. I have come across an explanation that "AND" is not supported in peer CLI.This may be the reason why couch db is not updated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46052567